# Are there philosophers who further develop ideas by Searle?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, philosophy-of-language, john-searle

I'm reading a bit about John Searle's philosophies of mind and language at the moment. In his language lectures he keeps emphasizing that his views aren't considered mainstream.

Are there any philosophers that are taking up (some of) his ideas and develop them further or in a different direction?

Answer (score 1):

Trust you are keeping ok.

I'm about to submit my thesis on Searle's theories in relation to power in the workplace linked to Foucault's positionality and subjectivity.

I can send you a summary when I have submitted if that is any help?

Comment: This is not an answer. Perhaps you wanted to post this as a comment and could not?

Comment: This looks like an email message…

Comment: Not sure if -1 is ok given that you need 50 reps to comment (I think)?

Answer (score 1):

hope a short list works:
Paul Brooks, Patty Churchland, Martha J. Farah, Gilbert Ryle, David Chalmers, Walter Glannon.

Comment: You should definitely add which works of them refer to Searle, as precise as possible. Nobody wants to start skimming through every book by the people you just named. Also, just adding the titles still wouldn't be enough to make that a *good* answer. For that, you should also add synopses or short abstracts.

Comment: @snipe I'll offer an accept for a tad more of context :) but +1 for the references